# User inputs multiple values and "skips Validation"

Tags: java, validation, user-input

I am just recreationally coding with a little program of mine and I discovered that I could effectively skip my validation by entering multiple values and placing a space in between them. For example, a snippet of my code is as follows:

```
while(counter == 0) {
    try{
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Good job");
        ++counter;
    } catch(InputMismatchException Exception) {
        System.out.println("You did something wrong");
        input.next();
    }
}
```

when it asks for the user input, I can just type "h 4" and it will accept it, sure it will say "you did something wrong" but it will also display "good job". What do I need to do to get my code to take the entire line into account and display "you did something wrong" if the user were to do something such as this.

I had been making my program with the idea in mind that the user would only enter one piece of information such as "hello" or "4". I did not take into account that they could enter "hello 4" until just now and my program is now suffering a bit because of it.

Comment: Could you say what the type of the variable "input" is?

Comment: it is a scanner variable I believe? The code for it is as follows:    "public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) to read the full line after a wrong input is given.

So replace this:

```
input.next();
```

with this in your catch block:

```
input.nextLine();
```

Explanation:

When you enter "h 4", `input.next();` reads the "h" and leaves the "4", which is a good value since is parseable to int and `int choice = input.nextInt();` reads this value when the loop starts again. Instead when you use `readLine` it will read the full wrong input "h 4" after displaying the message, loop again and wait until a new value is given.

Comment: Alright so that roughly works, but the program terminates when I enter an incorrect value and it does not display "You did something wrong", how can I get the message to display, and for the loop to start again and ask the user for another input?

Comment: I have tested it and the program doesn't terminate. It just wait for a new value: http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/1077598
.

Comment: My bad, I forgot I was testing out some other potential solutions and I forgot to change it back to how the code was originally, it does work as you stated, thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, just tested it and the problem re-occurs if I reverse the input, such as with "4 h". And I cant put my "choice" variable as an "input.nextLine()" because it states that "String Cannot be converted to int". would I have to include "parseInt" in some way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes. You could use `int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());` but instead of catching an `InputMismatchException` you would have to change it to `NumberFormatException`, i.e. the exception thrown by `Integer.parseInt` if the given value isn't a valid integer. In this case you wouldn't need `input.nextLine();` anymore in your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you need to check if there is any white space character in the input string. Enter one piece of information means any separated word I think. So in order to do that you can do following:

```
String s = input.nextLine();
if(containsWhiteSpace(s)){
    System.out.println("You did something wrong");
}else{
    System.out.println("Good job");
}
```

And the containsWhiteSpace function implementation is:

```
public static boolean containsWhiteSpace(final String testCode){
      if(testCode != null){
           for(int i = 0; i < testCode.length(); i++){
               if(Character.isWhitespace(testCode.charAt(i))){
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }
       return false;
}
```